# How to subtract the camera movements in Unity - Vuforia using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-camera, vuforia

The 3D model (Virtual Object) that is rendered by the Vuforia will always look at camera. I.e the model will be in the center of the screen when the Android camera is moved.
I'm not using any target.I want the model not to move but to stay at the spot where I place it with a button. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to "place" a model on a real world object and have it stay there (on the real world object) when you move your camera?

Answer (score 0):

In the Hierarchy panel,Drag your model into "MainCamera" by doing that you make the model act as a child to MainCamera,which will make model to move with the Camera (i.e).. it will be centered all the time,but make sure after you drag the model to the camera change the model's position to (0,0,0) as the model is in the local position of the Camera,I hope this might help you!

Answer (score 0):

In Vuforia there is a prefab called a UserDefinedTargetBuilder (Assets > Vuforia > Prefabs > UserDefinedTargetBuilder). Rather than rewrite everything the Vuforia team has already written I'll just link some very helpful guides on how to do this:

See [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/User-Defined-Targets-Guide) for an explanation on User Defined Targets.

See [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples) to download the Vuforia sample projects for Unity. In this there includes a UDT project that is very helpful.

And see [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/How-To-Developer-for-User-Defined-Targets-in-Unity) for a good guide on how to control the creation of the UDT.

Now as for always facing the Camera, Unity has a function called [`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) that takes, as an argument, the `Transform` of the GameObject you want to look at. This essentially, alligns the z-axis (the forward axis) or your object with the z-axis of the object you want to look at.